# HP Universal Printing Driver (UPD) 7.0

Tags: exception, driver

I have downloaded the most recent UPD PCL6 driver from HP home page. Its version 7.0.
We are using a solution call HP Access Control (16.8.1) which is a so called pull print solution.
I created a queue on my Windows Server 2016 and created a port. The HP Access Control comes along with its own port monitor.
I assigned the port to the queue and when I open the printer properties I get an error:

**Function address 0x00007FFEB9E06402 caused a protection fault. (exception code 0xc0000005)**

I have done this installation some time ago with the same version of HP Access Control and there all worked. Unfortunately I deleted that VM. But I believe I had an older version of UPD installed. Server operating system was also WS 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted the same question in the HP forum and got an answer.
For those who are interested:

**

> The current UPD driver seems to have an issue if you assign it to
> ports like LPT1 or File or 3rd party port monitors like those from
> pull print solutions.
>
> There seems to be a simple workaround:
>
> If you can access a printer that is in your network, then you can
> create a direct TCP/IP port and assign it to the queue you are having
> problems with.
>
> Then you can open properties or any other menu you get this error and
> then make the changes you would like to do.
>
> You can then re-assign the queue to the port which caused the error.
>
> Alternatively, if you still have an older UPD version and that still
> is fine for you then you can install the older version.
>
> You should keep in mind though that the older version may not support
> brand new printer models from HP.
>
> But if you have not the latest freshly released models you should be
> fine.
> **